# Print the maximum possible quotient of array A

Tags: javascript, dynamic-programming

Given an array A of N integers. Your teacher has asked you to find the maximum quotient of the array. Quotient of an array A of size N can be calculated in the following way:

1. Let the sum of the N elements of array A be X.
2. Let pre[] be another array of size N in which for every index i (1 <= i <= N), prei gives us the sum of elements A1 + A2 +. . + Ai.
3. Quotient of the array A will be equal to the summation of the floored value of X/prei over every value of i from 1 to N.

You can swap any two elements of the array A. FInd the maximum possible quotient of array A.

Input

First line of the input contains a single integer N.

The second line contains N space-separated integers Ai

Constraints:

1 <= N <= 10^5

1 <= Ai <= 10^8

Output

Print the maximum possible quotient of array A.

Example

Sample Input:

3

1 1 3

Sample Output:

8

Explaination:

Array pre[] = [1, 2, 5]

Sum X of array A = 5

Quotient of array A = 5/1 + 5/2 + 5/5 = 5 + 2 + 1 = 8

It can be proved that their is no greater quotient of array A possible

```
var furthest = function(n, arr) {
  // Sort the array in non-decreasing order
 arr.sort((a, b) =\> a - b);

// Calculate prefix sum array
    let pre = new Array(n).fill(0);
    pre[0] = arr[0];
    for (let i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        pre[i] = pre[i - 1] + arr[i];
    }

// Calculate maximum quotient
    let maxQuotient = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        let quotient = pre[i] * (i + 1) + (pre[n - 1] - pre[i]);
        maxQuotient = Math.max(maxQuotient, quotient);
    }

    return maxQuotient;

};
```

Where the code is wrong getting output 15 instead of 8 ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the sorted array is good enough to calculate the largest quotient.

```js
var furthest = function(n, arr) {
  // Sort the array in non-decreasing order
 arr.sort((a, b) => a - b);

// Calculate prefix sum array
    let pre = new Array(n).fill(0);
    pre[0] = arr[0];
    for (let i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        pre[i] = pre[i - 1] + arr[i];
    }
    let X = pre[n-1]

// Calculate maximum quotient
    let maxQuotient = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        maxQuotient += parseInt(X/pre[i])
    }

    return maxQuotient;

};
```